# knockout js css biniding doesn't save changes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

knockout js css biniding doesn't save changes after div's class was changed:
My model contain 2 properties:

```
man: '',
woman: 'active'
```

And I have 2 element in dom, which classes can be changed.

```
<input type='button' value='Is MAN?' class='' data-bind='css: man'>
<input type='button' value='Is WOMAN?' class='' data-bind='css: woman'>
```

I want to change my model's properties along through with changing html element classes.
For example: if we add class 'active' to

```
<input data-bind='css: man' class='active' />
```

our model property 'man' becomes 'active'. And other way to.

Work example on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24843/

Comment: because you are modifying class via jquery ko observables has no idea what you are doing .

Comment: Thanks, Do I have to modify class with some ko methods? How better to manage it? in data-bind attr?

Comment: yes you need to do by `ko` let me try giving a working sample .

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24845/ . modified your way of doing . hoe that helps . let me know

Comment: Wow, it's something new for me. Work's great, I'll thing it over with my project. Thank you very much! And this example also spreads to data-bind by attr? I mean if you bind attr, you have to change it only with ko, right?

Comment: yes thats right .! by above way you can manage things easily .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some modifications which makes code manageable

Idea is to leave the setting of `class` to html controls to viewModel based on Boolean prop's true/false

**view:**

```
<!-- ko foreach:people -->
PERSON DATA
<br/>
<input type='button' value='Is MAN?' class='' data-bind="css:{'active':man},,click:mClick" ><br/>
<input type='button' value='Is WOMAN?' class='' data-bind="css:{'active' : woman},click:wClick"><br/><br/>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**viewModel:**

```
var data = {
    persons:[
        new PersonViewModel({
            man: false,
            woman: true
        }),
        new PersonViewModel({
            man: true,
            woman: false
        })
    ]
};

function PersonViewModel(data){
    var self = this;
    self.man = ko.observable(data.man);
    self.woman = ko.observable(data.woman);
     self.mClick=function(){
      self.man(!self.man())
    }
      self.wClick=function(){
      self.woman(!self.woman())
    }
}

var applicationVM = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray(data.persons);
    self.savechanges = function() {
        alert(ko.toJSON(self.people));
    };  
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings( new applicationVM(data) );
});
```

sample working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24845/)**